# How do I selectively center text?

Tags: html, css, ionic3, centering

I have this kind of header in ionic 3

[image]

What I wanted to do was center the home title while ignoring the space occupied by my ion avatar

[image]

Here's what I tried

```
<ion-header >

  <ion-navbar style="text-align: center;">
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button round clear (click)="goToAccountPage()">
        <ion-item class="transparent">
            <ion-avatar item-end>
                <!-- <img src="{{photo_url}}"> -->
                <img [src]="photo_url" >
              </ion-avatar>
        </ion-item>

      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

and this

```
<ion-header >

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title text-center>Home</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button round clear (click)="goToAccountPage()">
        <ion-item class="transparent">
            <ion-avatar item-end>
                <!-- <img src="{{photo_url}}"> -->
                <img [src]="photo_url" >
              </ion-avatar>
        </ion-item>

      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

And then I tried implementing it directly and not inline

```
 <ion-title class="center">Home</ion-title>

.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

To those who will encounter the same problem, please go to nourza's awesome and responsive answer :)

From this

[image]

to this

[image]
5]

Comment: If your question is related to CSS then you why didn't you add CSS to your question?

Comment: Would this count? style="text-align: center;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 .center{
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
```

Comment: I did, sir    style="text-align: center;" :)

Comment: Try to add !important in the end of the element ext-align: center !important;

Comment: text-align: center !important; also didn't make the title budge

Comment: Updated my answer please check it again

Comment: YOU DA MAAAN! I was also trying to do it via positioning, I put position absolute then played with the bottom and left attribute only to find out that although I achieved centering, it wasn't responsive. Many Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following solution to selectively center text:

```
{
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer of why this would solve the OP's question. I doubt that just adding position absolute will fix it

Comment: @SuperDJ can you wait his answer?

Comment: Maybe if you also add in the css - width: 100%;

Comment: What do you mean by "wait his answer"

Comment: It also didn't work. might be because there are already underlying css rules that conflict with my css

Comment: @add also left: 0;